# Lambda, NLTK Data and S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nltk

I am deploying a Lambda function that uses Python + NLTK Data.
The problem is that the data folder is 3.3G and lambda upload doesn't support more than a certain limit of data storage.

Some solutions here are to remove all the folders and archive I don't use in this function but this can be a temporary solution.

I was thinking of other solutions like using NLTK data from S3. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SageMaker, creating a Docker image with NLTK and Python libraries [AWS SageMaker - Create your own Docker Image and run Customized Algorithms](https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/tree/master/AWS%20SageMaker), or even install NLTK in ElasticBeanstalk [Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/tree/master/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk)